# Rails method for counting rows returns "wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am graphing the amount of votes for each vote value (1-4 stars) in my view, and have a method in my controller to count the number of votes (rows).

My controller (/app/controllers/entry_controller.rb):

```
before_filter :count_votes, :only => :track

...

protected
def count_votes(value, id)
  Vote.where(:value => value, :entry_id => id).count
end
```

My view (/app/views/entries/track.html.erb):

```
{ amount: '1', value: <%= count_votes(1, @entry.id) %>},
```

But Rails gives me

```
ArgumentError in EntriesController#track: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
```

I am sending it two values (1 and @entry.id). What should I do to make my method work?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: My bet is it's not in `count_votes`, but in `track` method, as error specified.

Comment: @MBO See, that's what's weird about it. It's not in #track at all

Comment: count_votes method expects 2 parameters, and when you are calling it in before filter, no argument is passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, not when I reread you question second time it stroked me:

You have method `#count_votes`, which is used as before filter. But for method to work as before filter, it cant' get any parameters. Filters are used to fetch data based on `params` (is fetch `@current_user`, fetch `@user` based on `params[:id]`) or check if current request is valid - user has permission to access this method (let it be based on some authorization library, or just check flags, check if record is available and so on).

You should not use before filter either as prerequisite for action, or as conditional test if this action should be accessible and if not then redirect. From your example neither of this is present.

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters.

Comment: Ah. How do you suggest I accomplish this instead?

Comment: @ColbyAley What do you want to accomplish by this method? Is it really necessary for it to be before fiter? Is it really **filter**?

Comment: You know, you're right. It should be a filter. For some reason I was under the impression that you could not use ActiveRecord from a filter. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass appropriate parameters to the before_filter call.

```
before_filter { |c| c.count_votes 1, @entry.id  }
```